# How can I execute a shell script at the end of SFTP execution?

Tags: bash, shell, ssh, sh, sftp

I have a shell script, in it I do `SFTP` and transfer my files to the remote host.

I can transfer files to remote host, but my parent shell script code, once `SFTP` is completed, can not execute.

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
echo "Starting SFTP..."
    cd "/Users/myuser/myfolder"
    sftp -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no" admin@myserver.myorg.com << END_SCRIPT
    cd /some/folder/on/remote/host
    put -r .
    bye
    END_SCRIPT
echo "Done."
```

I do not see "Done." getting printed on console. Any clues?

Comment: Is your script really indented like appears in the question?

Comment: yes, it is. I am new to this. Should I not indent it?

Comment: Unindenting it (or just the END_SCRIPT line) will definitely fix the problem

Comment: Cool, it fixes the issue :) Thanks. But, what is the reasoning?

Comment: Alternatively if the indentation is via tab characters you can use the `<<- END_SCRIPT` syntax (note the dash symbol)

Comment: Ok, can you please post this as answer along with reasoning? I will mark as accepted, thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is due to indentation. There are two possible solutions

1. either get rid of the indentation (at least for the `END_SCRIPT` line),
2. or make sure that the indentation is via tabs rather than spaces and use the `<<-` rather than `<<` redirection operator.

You must also make sure that there are no blanks after `END_SCRIPT`.

> **Here Documents**
>
> This type of redirection instructs the shell to  read  input  from 
>   the    current source until a line containing **only delimiter (with no
>   trailing    blanks)** is seen.  All of the lines read up to that point
>   are then  used    as the standard input for a command.
>
> The format of here-documents is:
>
> ```
>       <<[-]word
>               here-document
>       delimiter
> ```
>
> No  parameter  and variable expansion, command substitution,
>   arithmetic    expansion, or pathname expansion is performed on word. 
>   If any  characters  in  word are quoted, the delimiter is the
>   result of quote removal    on word, and the lines in the here-document
>   are not expanded.  If  word    is  unquoted, all lines of the
>   here-document are subjected to parameter    expansion, command
>   substitution, and arithmetic expansion, the  character  sequence 
>   `\<newline>`  is  ignored, and `\` must be used to quote the    characters
>   `\`, `$`, and `.
>
> **If the redirection operator is `<<-`, then all leading tab characters
>   are    stripped  from  input  lines  and  the line containing
>   delimiter.  This    allows here-documents within shell scripts to be
>   indented in a  natural    fashion.**

Answer (score 1):

The heredocs require that what appears next to the `<<` should be
exactly produced as such to end the heredoc.

In your case indenting introduced tabs (or possibly spaces before) heredoc delim `END_SCRIPT` so that it couldn't be considered as a delimiter anymore. 
So the `sftp` command went on looking for a delimiter which it never found.

Below is the format.

```
command <<HEREDOC_DELIM

HEREDOC_DELIM 
# Note that nothing should be put in front of HEREDOC_DELIM - no indents.
```